# how can i pass the data between two functions of a service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to create a multi step form in which I have made two different views and two different controllers I am trying to pass the data from view 1 to function defined in service and then trying to access this data in another function of same service. 
The following is the service I have written: service.js

```
var EmployeeService = angular.module('EmployeeService',[])
.service('AddEmployee', function($resource){
     var Employee = $resource('/api/meetups');
        var emp_email="";
    this.email = function(email){
        var emp_email = email;
            return emp_email;
    };

    this.personal = function(first_name){
            var employee = new Employee();
            employee.email = emp_email;
             employee.first_name = first_name;
              employee.$save();
    };
});
```

I am trying access emp_email variable of email function into personal function. but I am not able to do so. is there any way I can use emp_email variable in my second function.

Following is the controller which is using services:

```
app.controller('mainCrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$location', 'AddEmployee', function ($scope, $resource, $location, AddEmployee){
  $scope.nextSection = function(){
  $scope.email = AddEmployee.email($scope.employeeEmail);
  };
}]);
app.controller('secondCrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$location', 'AddEmployee', function ($scope, $resource, $location, AddEmployee){
   $scope.secondSection = function(){
   $scope.first_name = AddEmployee.personal($scope.first_name);
  };
}]);
```

nextSection function will be executed when user fills email and hits on next section and secondSection function will be executed when user enters first_name in second view and hits submit.

how can I pass the data between two functions in services? any sort of help is really appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're creating a second "emp_email" variable in your e-mail function, so the email you are assigning is going to a local emp_email variable within the e-mail function rather than the emp_email variable in the service function.

So remove the var and change

```
this.email = function(email){
    var emp_email = email;
        return emp_email;
};
```

to

```
this.email = function(email){
    emp_email = email;
        return emp_email;
};
```

That should allow you to share the emp_email variable between functions.

Comment: No problem. That was a subtle error that can easily be overlooked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var emp_email = email;
```

with

```
return emp_email = email;
```

(you modify the local variable)